# C++ VS - Required DLL to another directory?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker, sdl-2

I am setting up an SDL project and want an organised file structure. Setting this up I don't actually have the DLL's in the same folder as the executable because it's more messy overall. I currently have them in a data folder like this:

```
-bin  
  -x86.exe  
  -x64.exe  
-data  
  -x86  
    -sdl2.dll  
  -x64  
    -sdl2.dll
```

Obviously I can't run it like that so I tried maybe using LoadLibrary to load the DLL's in a wmain entrypoint with simply:

```
#if _WIN64
    std::cout << LoadLibraryA("..\\data\\x64\\glew32.dll") << "\n";
    std::cout << LoadLibraryA("..\\data\\x64\\sdl2.dll") << "\n";
#else
    std::cout << LoadLibraryA("..\\data\\x86\\glew32.dll") << "\n";
    std::cout << LoadLibraryA("..\\data\\x86\\sdl2.dll") << "\n";
#endif
```

But this still gives me the error.
The error only occurs after this when I call SDL_Init

How would I maybe set the location of these DLL's to be in different places and get it at runtime because maybe the data folder won't have sub directories when I release etc. I need to havbe multiple locations these DLL's could actually be in.

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdj1r.png)

Comment: Do the calls to LoadLibrary succeed?  Does the error occur as soon as you attempt to call SDL_Init, or does it occur somewhere inside SDL_Init?  Have you tried using absolute paths rather than relative paths?  (NB: as a general rule, all DLLs should be in the same directory as the executable; you're just causing trouble for yourself by putting it somewhere different.)

Comment: The LoadLibrary succeeds on both attempts, testing it with console output. I believe it's somewhere inside SDL_Init as it'll check if it can find the DLL

Comment: OK, so this is an SDL-specific question, that wasn't obvious to me at first glance.  I'll leave it to the experts.

Comment: I didn't want to make it that I'm not sure if it actually is. I had a look at the SDL_Init function which is what I called and couldn't find it throwing that error

Comment: Are you sure SDL_Init isn't actually *in* the DLL?

Comment: Yeh but it's something to do with Windows/Linking because it's saying it can't find that DLL for some reason maybe something compile time I am not sure

Comment: @ReeceWard wait, you just `LoadLibrary` and then use functions declared in `#include` files without `GetProcAddress` on each function? I don't think it's a way to go. You can copy required dlls to executable's directory, link with static libraries, or go fully dynamic with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. (as added bonus, SDL2 have means for end user to override itself with newer dll even if you linked with static)

Comment: Why are you using GLEW in DLL form?  You can add `glew.c` to your project files & skip the DLL entirely.